# Как инициализировать двумерный массив в классе?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

  const int n = 8;
  int dx[] = {2, 2, 1, 1, -1, -1, -2, -2};
  int dy[] = {1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2, 1, -1};



  class HorseMove
  {
  public:

      int **Solution = new int *[n];

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            Solution[i] =  new int *[n];
        }

      bool Success = false;

      int Step(int i, int x, int y)
      {
          if (Success)
            {
              return 1;
            }
          if ((x < 0) || (x >= n) || (y < 0) || (y >= n) || (Solution[x][y] > 0))
              {
                  return 1;
              }

          Solution[x][y] = i;

          if (i = n * n)
          {
              Success = true;
          }
          else
          {
              for(int k = 0; k <= 7; k++)
              {
                  Step(i + 1, x + dx[k], y + dy[k]);
              }
          }
          if (!Success)
          {
              Solution[x][y] = 0;
          }
      }
  };

  const int x0 = 1, y0 = 3;

  int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

        HorseMove Chess;
        Chess.Step(1, x0, y0);
        if (Chess.Success)
        {
            cout << Chess.Solution;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Это у вас точно такой код? Сразу после `public:` не объявление члена, а голый код?... И - все же поясните, что вы хотите сделать, из вашего кода непонятно, где именно проблемы...

Comment: Дружище, прочти какую-нибудь хорошую книгу для начинающих, а то твой код очень уж странный. Начни с того, что не используй C-style двумерные массивы, сырые указатели, глобальные переменные и константы, не пиши названия переменных с больших букв (ни в CamelCase, ни в stl_case так не делается), приучи себя по возможности не использовать  `using namespace std`, а везде приписывать `std::` при указании функций, например (`std::cout`), в будущем тебе это пригодится. И да, почитай, что такое классы и зачем они нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас заранее известны значения для инициализации, и поддерживается С++11, то вот так:

```
class Test
{
    int a[2][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5}};
};
```

Если не знаете - то используйте векторы:

```
class Test
{
    vector<vector<int>> v {{0,1,2},{3,4,5}};
};
```

Comment: Вы наверное имели в виду не "значения для инициализации", а "размерность массива"